# Apache Pig: Dynamic columns

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

I've a dataset (CSV) that has three value columns (v1, 2 and 3) with a value. The description of the value is stored as a comma separated string in the column 'keys'.

```
| v1 | v2 | v3 | keys  |
| A  | C  | E  | X,Y,Z |
```

Using Pig I would like to load this information in a HBase table where the Column Family is C and the Column Qualifier is the key.

```
| C:X | C:Y | C:Z |
| A   | C   | E   |
```

Has anyone done this before and would like to share this knowledge?

Another option is to store a map (key#value) in a HBase column. But I'm not sure if this is flexible for querying the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem

**test.pig:**

```
REGISTER data.py using jython as myfuncs

A = LOAD 'data' using PigStorage('|') AS (
    id:chararray,
    date:chararray,
    v1:chararray,
    v2:chararray,
    v3:chararray,
    keys:chararray,
);

B = FOREACH A {
GENERATE
    id,
    date,
    myfuncs.dataToMap(STRSPLIT(keys, ','), TOTUPLE(v1, v2, v3)) as kv;
}

STORE B INTO 'pig_table' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage( 'e:date kv:*' );
```

**data.py:**

```
import org.apache.pig.data.DataType as DataType
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.SchemaUtil as SchemaUtil

@outputSchema("ud:map[]")
def dataToMap(keys, values):

result = dict()
keys = list(keys)
values = list(values)

try:
    while True:
        values.remove(None)
except ValueError:
    pass

for idx in range(len(keys)):
    result[keys[idx]] = values[idx]

return result
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the common problem while processing multi-structure  schema. If you really want to try this with MAP type  then it is a bad idea.

You can try this with MapReduce. MapReduce is best solution for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any chance you can give some more details or examples?

Comment: you want MapReduce example?

Comment: I still prefere to solve it within pig, but i'll give MR a try. Do you have a example?