# Add Variable Number of Columns for Column Family in HBase Using Pig

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, hadoop2, hue

I need to load from Pig to HBase using HBaseStorage and I can't figure out how to load with a variable number of columns for a specific column family.(With a known number of columns it is straightforward)

Data that looks like this: (spaces added for readibility)

```
Id,ItemId,Count,Date
1 ,1     ,2    ,2015-02-01
2 ,2     ,2    ,2015-02-02
3 ,1     ,2    ,2015-02-03
```

And I have an HBase table with rowkey and one column family called Attributes. So I load first the csv using:

```
A = LOAD 'items.csv' USING PigStorage(',') 
as (Id,ItemId,Count:chararray, CreationDate:chararray);
```

And now I want to group them by ItemId so I do the following:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ItemId, TOTUPLE(Date, Count);

C = GROUP B BY ItemId
```

So I get my data nicely grouped, with the key and then the tuples with Date and Count:

```
1   {(2015-02-03, 2),(2015-02-01, 2)}
2   {(2015-02-02, 2)}
```

And what I am aiming for in HBase is to have one row with two columns, with the date and count:

```
Rowkey = 1 (Attributes.2015-02-03,2) (Attributes.2015-02-01,2)
Rowkey = 2 (Attributes.2015-02-02,2)
```

And this is the part I am struggling with, how do I define that I have a variable number of columns? I have tried the following as well as multiple other combinations:

```
STORE onlygroups into 'hbase://mytable'
USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('Attributes:*');
```

But get several errors, for example this one:

```
ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. org.apache.pig.data.InternalCachedBag 
    cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

I have also tried using TOMAP but does not work either. Any suggestions?

Note: the recommended solution identified as duplicate does not solve my issue, it basically recommends using MapReduce and my data structure is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Pig: Dynamic columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866697/apache-pig-dynamic-columns)

Comment: Thanks @RahulSharma but I already tried it and did not work. Also on that one it says to try MapReduce, not really solving it with Pig.

Comment: HbaseStorage can adds dynamically columns but here your each record has id and bag of tuples which is causing the error. In this case you have to write your UDF to explode PIG bag to individual tuples then try it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to load data to HBase your data in PIG should be in the following format:

```
tuple(key, map(col_qual, col_value))
```

In your case:

```
(1,[2015-02-03#2])
(1,[2015-02-01#2])
(2,[2015-02-02#2])
```

You can create this type of object right from your initial data:

```
A = LOAD 'items.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (Id,ItemId,Count:chararray,CreationDate:chararray);
storeHbase = FOREACH A GENERATE ItemId, TOMAP(CreationDate, Count);
```

Or if you want to achieve it after some grouping by key:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ItemId, TOTUPLE(CreationDate, Count) as pair;
C = GROUP B BY ItemId;
storeHbase = FOREACH C {
    Tmp = FOREACH $1 GENERATE TOMAP(pair.CreationDate,pair.Count);
    GENERATE group, FLATTEN(Tmp);
};
```

And after all you can load your data to the HBase:

```
STORE storeHbase into 'hbase://mytable' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('Attributes:*');
```

where `mytable` is your HBase table and `Attributes` is your column family.

Comment: Thank you very much @maxeneftt! Let me give it a shot and I will come back to mark this as resolved

Comment: Thanks @maxteneff but it didn't work. On your first solution I get the cells replaced so instead of having two cells for the itemid, I get a single cell. On your second solution I get three rows.

Comment: If you want to run these scripts your data should be exactly as you defined in the beginning of your question. If it's not then you should transform your data in PIG to the format I defined in the beginning of the answer. And only after that you can load it to HBase.

Comment: Anyway my answer is not about concrete scripts but about the format of data you should achieve in PIG to be possible to load it to HBase